# How to configure Maven to keep "Maven Dependencies" in Modulepath?

Tags: java, maven, module-path

I've got a simple Java project with Maven.

By default dependencies loaded through Maven end up in a **"Maven dependencies"** library which is added to the **class-path**.

In eclipse it looks like this:
[image]

For whatever reason, I need those dependencies in the **module-path**, like so:
[image]

My Problem is that every time i run maven update, it **resets** the "Maven Dependencies" library to **class-path**.

How can the project or pom file be configured to **keep the libary in module-path**?

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file?

Comment: Of course, that's the whole point

Comment: Does your build work on plain command line? Which Eclipse do you use ?

Comment: yes it does... well, when the dependencies are in module-path.
Eclipse version 4.12.0

Comment: So maybe I misunderstand this but it sounds as it is an Eclipse issue? Why do you need them in module path in Eclipse? What is the real problem here?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an eclipse issue, or not... the problem is that i have no idea how to configure pom to ensure the autogenerated "Maven dependencies" library is kept in Module path

Comment: So in the ned you don't know what kind of issue you have except that it is not shown in Module path in Eclipse?

Comment: alright, let's try this one more time... 
the basic issue is that mvn update moves my dependecies from module path to class path... all i'm looking for is a way to configure pom to keep dependencies in modulepath.  not sure why i need to have any more issues for it to become a valid problem. however, to give a bit more clarity to the issue, i'm trying to write a modular (as in java modules with module-info.java and all that) api structured into modular subdependencies, and for whatever reason not relevant to the issue at hand, the dependencies need to be in module path.